# Testflight upload fails with an error in the azure pipeline

Tags: ios, flutter, azure-pipelines, testflight, fastlane

I am trying to upload an ipa generated from a pipeline task to testflight, but I keep getting this error,

```
2022-09-08T19:15:04.3027660Z [19:15:04]: Transporter transfer failed.
2022-09-08T19:15:04.3035460Z [19:15:04]: 
2022-09-08T19:15:04.3038030Z [19:15:04]: iTMSTransporter could not generate an itmsp: null
2022-09-08T19:15:04.3148450Z An exception has occurred: null
2022-09-08T19:15:04.5690040Z [19:15:04]: [iTMSTransporter]  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
2022-09-08T19:15:04.5692520Z 
2022-09-08T19:15:04.5693940Z [19:15:04]: [iTMSTransporter]  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
2022-09-08T19:15:04.5694840Z 
2022-09-08T19:15:04.5695950Z [19:15:04]: [iTMSTransporter]  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
2022-09-08T19:15:04.5696630Z 
2022-09-08T19:15:04.5697520Z [19:15:04]: [iTMSTransporter]  at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
2022-09-08T19:15:04.5698140Z 
2022-09-08T19:15:04.5699110Z [19:15:04]: [iTMSTransporter]  at com.apple.transporter.launcher.Application.start(Application.java:450)
2022-09-08T19:15:04.5699870Z 
2022-09-08T19:15:04.5701020Z [19:15:04]: [iTMSTransporter]  at com.apple.transporter.launcher.Application.main(Application.java:947)
2022-09-08T19:15:04.5701970Z 
2022-09-08T19:15:04.5703840Z [19:15:04]: [iTMSTransporter] 
2022-09-08T19:15:04.5704400Z 
2022-09-08T19:15:04.5705320Z [19:15:04]: [iTMSTransporter]  
2022-09-08T19:15:04.5705520Z 
2022-09-08T19:15:04.5706710Z [19:15:04]: [iTMSTransporter]  
2022-09-08T19:15:04.5706970Z 
2022-09-08T19:15:04.5707850Z [19:15:04]: [iTMSTransporter]  
2022-09-08T19:15:04.5708140Z 
2022-09-08T19:15:04.5708820Z [19:15:04]: [iTMSTransporter] Error Summary
2022-09-08T19:15:04.5709040Z 
2022-09-08T19:15:04.5709430Z [19:15:04]: [iTMSTransporter]  
2022-09-08T19:15:04.5709600Z 
2022-09-08T19:15:04.5710090Z [19:15:04]: [iTMSTransporter]     iTMSTransporter could not generate an itmsp: null
2022-09-08T19:15:04.5710380Z 
2022-09-08T19:15:04.5710820Z [19:15:04]: [iTMSTransporter]     An exception has occurred: null
2022-09-08T19:15:04.5711280Z 
2022-09-08T19:15:04.5713560Z [19:15:04]: [iTMSTransporter] [2022-09-08 19:15:04 UTC] <main> DBG-X: Returning 1
2022-09-08T19:15:04.5713960Z 
2022-09-08T19:15:04.5714350Z [19:15:04]: iTunes Transporter output above ^
2022-09-08T19:15:04.5714900Z [19:15:04]: iTMSTransporter could not generate an itmsp: null
2022-09-08T19:15:04.5715430Z An exception has occurred: null
2022-09-08T19:15:04.5716020Z Return status of iTunes Transporter was 1: iTMSTransporter could not generate an itmsp: null
2022-09-08T19:15:04.5717110Z \nAn exception has occurred: null
2022-09-08T19:15:04.5718220Z The call to the iTMSTransporter completed with a non-zero exit status: 1. This indicates a failure.
2022-09-08T19:15:04.5918110Z 
2022-09-08T19:15:04.5920580Z [!] Error uploading ipa file: 
2022-09-08T19:15:04.5921290Z  
2022-09-08T19:15:04.6299370Z ##[error]Error: The process '/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/bin/fastlane' failed with exit code 1
2022-09-08T19:15:04.6329380Z ##[section]Finishing: Publish to the App Store TestFlight track
```

Any reason why I am getting this. I couldn't find an exact cause for this issue in other threads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was coming basically because I've configured multiple schemes but I haven't defined build numbers for some schemes. The error generated from the pipeline is pretty ambiguous.A more detailed answer on validating your ipa incase you got this type of a similar issue is posted here,

https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/discussions/20636